# After update, I can't change launcher icon size

Tags: unity, updates, virtualbox, launcher

I have 6 Ubuntu vm's running in Oracle Virtual Box (3 on my work machine and 3 on my home machine). All of them are version 16.04.

I don't recall the date but it seems like after some update I did between July 8th and now, the launcher icon size changed to it's default value (48?) and using that slider in the appearance screen doesn't do a thing...on all 6 vm's.

I've already issued 'unity --reset' but that just makes the screen flash and then it goes back to where it was before.

This is really weird that this happened to all 6 of my vm's on 2 different machines after updating them on the same day.  I've been waiting for someone else to post about this but I'm not seeing anything related to the "Launcher icon size" and "version 16.04".  Like I said, the only thing that's changed on these machines are the updates I do so I can't help but think that one of the updates did something.

I have one "clean" vm on each machine that I clone when I want to test something out. The only thing I've done on the "clean" vm's is perform updates and this happened to them as well.

TIA,
John

Update: I just updated the 2 ubuntu images on my MacBook (a third machine) and I got the same result with the Launcher icon size. I'm unable to resize the Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this problem in 14.04 after updating this morning. The settings in the system settings manager and the unity tweak tool both do nothing.

I'm too much of a noob to discern which of the updates in the apt history log might be responsible.